# PHP Header Already Sent Error

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, header

I am having trouble with my code.It is supposed to redirect to a page if the login is okay.I am getting a successfully login but I am getting a error with the header forward.Here is the line which the problem is occurring:

```
header("Location: members.php");
```

Here is the error message:
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Here is my full code for the page if it helps:

```
<?php 
    // Connects to your Database 
    include("dbconnect.php");
    mysql_select_db("maxgee_close2");
    //Checks if there is a login cookie

    if(isset($_COOKIE['ID_my_site']))
     //if there is, it logs you in and directes you to the members page
    { 
        $username = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site']; 
        $password = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site'];
        $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'")or die(mysql_error());
        while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check )) 
        {
            if ($pass != $info['password'])
            {
            }
            else
            {
                header("Location: members.php");
            }
        }
    }
    //if the login form is submitted 
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // if form has been submitted
     // makes sure they filled it in
        if(!$_POST['username'] | !$_POST['password']) {
            die('You did not fill in a required field.');
        }
        // checks it against the database

        if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $_POST['email'] = addslashes($_POST['email']);
        }
        $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$_POST['username']."'")or die(mysql_error());

        //Gives error if user dosen't exist
        $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);
        if ($check2 == 0) {
            die('That user does not exist in our database. <a href=add.php>Click Here to Register</a>');
        }
        while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))  
        {
            $_POST['password'] = stripslashes($_POST['password']);

            $info['password'] = stripslashes($info['password']);

            $_POST['password'] = md5($_POST['password']);

            //gives error if the password is wrong

            if ($_POST['password'] != $info['password']) {
                die('Incorrect password, please try again.');
            }
            else 
            { 
                // if login is ok then we add a cookie 
                $_POST['username'] = stripslashes($_POST['username']); 
                $hour = time() + 3600; 

              //then redirect them to the members area and the line with the error
              header("Location: members.php");
            }
        } 
      }
      else
      { 
        // if they are not logged in
         ?>
         <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
         <h1>Login</h1>
         Username:
        <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="40"> 
        Password:
        <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="50"> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
        </form> 
    <?php 
     } 
     include("topsite.php");
    ?>
```

Comment: No problem you should accept one of the answers that helped you, and welcome to stack overflow!

Comment: I will....I Still have the restriction where I have to wait 15 minutes and then I will! @StackOverflowed

Comment: You have some SQL injection vulnerabilities as well - setting the `$_COOKIE['ID_my_site']` value to `'; DROP TABLE users; SELECT '` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written

```
$password = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site'];
```

But you are comparing $pass with $info['password'] and it should be

```
    if ($password != $info['password']){

    } else {

        header("Location: members.php");
    }
```

You can modify your query in a better way by writing

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'")or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($check) == 0) header("Location: members.php");
```

Comment: How does that solve the original issue?

Comment: if $pass is not define, it will throw error which acts as an output and that is triggering the header error. Basically it prints before the header.

Comment: @JanDvorak I asked for him to look for a different problem...he is just helping me out!

Comment: `display errors` should always be disabled on production. Good point anyways.

Comment: Worth noting that the mysql php extension is deprecated and that the code contains sql injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: @doublesharp, I dont disagree. But he has asked for how to rectify the error and not good practices to follow.

Answer (score 1):

There is a space at the starting of your code..

`<?php`

Try after removing that.

For more info look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Comment: Thank you!My bad stupid mistake!

Comment: Can you check the code and see if there is a problem with adding the cookie because I am having trouble with the members page finding the cookie?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a space before your `<?php` tag. It looks like it's there in your example.

Comment: Thank you!My bad stupid mistake!

Answer (score 1):

There's a space before php tag. Any space outside of your PHP tags will be considered whitespace for output.

Comment: Thank you!My bad stupid mistake!

Answer (score 0):

its a good practice to make php files without the closing tag:

```
?>
```

just write something like:

```
//end of file
```

you can see it for example in codeIgniter php files

Comment: WHY??? I disagree with this unsourced claim!!!

Comment: because after the closing php tag may be some whitespaces, that is the only reason

Comment: you mean, "you have to choose between malformed PHP, breaking the UNIX convention and having to `ob` any includes before headers"? Still a good point. I vote for #2 - breaking the UNIX convention.

Comment: @JanDvorak What UNIX convention do you speak of?

Comment: @jan: that's a recommendation by ramus. ;-)

Comment: @itachi who is ramus? Link please

Comment: maybe Rasmus Lerdorf? :), i just readed about that in codeigniter documentation, thats all)

Comment: @Jack the convention of ending all text files with a newline, dating back to the times when the unix progams were as stupid as possible meaning they would not insert the newline for you when listing the file.

Answer (score 0):

[same question/problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703560/cannot-modify-header-information-on-static-function/12703581#12703581)

try to add `ob_start()` at start and `ob_flush()` or `ob_end_flush()` at end

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
<?php ob_start();?> // top of the page

<?php ob_flush();?> // at the end of the page
```

these two are used to start the **output buffer**. if we use this the output to the user will throw only after the exicution of each line in that document

and try to remove the space before **session_start()**.

```
eg: <?php session_start();?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
```

Comment: buffering the entire script is bad for your performance.

Comment: yea. i know that. but its help me a lot when the redirection problem arise. And i didt get any other way.